# "Write me a description..."

Tags: verbs, prepositions, word-usage

Please help me. Here is a piece of my English exercise. The textbook was written by British authors.

Now, class, I’d like you all to write … a description of your last holiday.
A.  me
B.  to me
C.  it me
D.  about me

The key gives the answer “A” - "me". Why is “B” ("to me") incorrect? How to explain that? I've studied the "write me/write to me" discussions on this site. Still, I don't understand.

Comment: “Write to me” means “send me a letter”. This is an instruction, a command. “Make me a sandwich”, “build me a house”, “write me a novel”.

Answer (score 1):

The verb **write** can take an indirect object and a direct object:

> Write me <sup>indirect</sup> a letter <sup>direct</sup>

Instead of an indirect object (a pronoun in the objective case— in the example above, **me**) we can have a prepositional phrase, **to me**, but in that case the order of the objects is reversed:

> Write a letter to me.